# Can I extract rows from one worksheet to another using criteria from one column using a formula?

Tags: excel, row, extract, formula, worksheet

I am trying to extract rows from this worksheet which have the same truck number (ex:4). My problem is that when I use the 'Advance Filter' it won't automatically update when I change the truck number.  I am sure I need to use a formula but it seems as though the formula is over my expertise or lack there of. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
   A         B               C           D          E
1 -Equipment-Serial Number---Done Date---Due Date---Truck Number                      
2 ------Coil ----------991---10/1/2012----7/12/13--------------4                      
3 ------Coil ----------992---10/1/2012----7/12/13--------------1                          
4 ------Coil ----------994---10/1/2012----7/12/13--------------4
```

Comment: Where do you want to extract the rows to?

Comment: Needs clarification. You want to take all the rows with truck number 4 and copy to another worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, a PivotTable might be easiest - simply put the `Truck number` into the filter field and filter for truck #4. Place all other fields in the row field, and design the pivot table to be "Tabular layout", "Do not show subtotals", "Do not show grand total" - and your result will look like this:

[image]

Now you only need to refresh the pivot table if you get any update!